# How to use Laravel package in my own package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package, composer-php

I'm developing a Role-Permission package in Laravel and I want to use this package;

[Laravel permission github](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Problem is I can not use some functions in the main project when I install this package in my own package. example "HasRoles"

My packages composer.json file

```
 "require": {
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Modul\\Permission\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Spatie\\Permission\\PermissionServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
```

main project composer file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Modul\\Permission\\": "packages/modul/permission/src"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

and my User model;

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
```

when I serve its show this error message...

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   (E_UNKNOWN) Trait 'Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles' not found

What am I doing wrong here?

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRUT0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnQll.png)

Comment: Have you installed this package? If you just changed `composer.json` manually then you need to do `composer update` for Composer to install it into your vendor folder.

Comment: i use "composer require spatie/laravel-permission " command

Comment: Are you serving laravel project that uses your package or some script that requires `vendor/autoload.php`?

Comment: maybe somthing happened before composer dumped its autoload files. try `composer dump-autoload` manually. just to be sure

Comment: If you are using this package inside your project, you need to update your project's `vendor` folder via composer.

Comment: i am serving laravel project that uses my package and i tried composer dumpautoload but nothing change

Comment: @EmreCanbulat one of your project's packages got updated. You need to pull those updates in for your project. Do `composer update yourpackage/name` (or `composer update` in general) **for your project** to bring in new changes and new dependency into it.

Comment: @d3jn I used both commands ( composer update yourpackage/name & composer update)  but the problem persists

Comment: @EmreCanbulat show us your project's composer.json then.

Comment: @d3jn ok, I shared

Comment: @EmreCanbulat i think i know what your problem is, check out the answer i've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are just autoloading your packages files into your project. This way your project's composer doesn't know anything about your package's dependencies (hence why `spatie/permission` package is not being installed).

The correct way to do this is to **require** your package into your project. Usually you would create a repository for your project, register it at https://packagist.org as `modul/permission` and then run `composer require modul/permission` for you project.

But if your package is still not fully developed, I would recommend you require it not from packagist, but from the so-called `path repository`. Inside your project's `composer.json` add the following section:

```
{
...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "packages/modul/permission"
        },
    ]
...
}
```

This will make composer look into your `packages/modul/permission` directory for your package when you require it. So do this and remove manual autoload of your package's source files from your project's `composer.json` (composer will use your package's autoload section to bind `/src` to `Module\Permission` namespace):

```
"psr-4": {
     "App\\": "app/",
     "Modul\\Permission\\": "packages/modul/permission/src" <--- remove this line
}
```

Lastly, run `composer require modul/permission`. Composer will find it inside the path repository we specified for him and symlink the `packages/modul/permission` directory to `vendor/modul/permission` and install it's dependencies as well.

Now you can edit your package inside `packages/modul/permission` folder. Once it's done be sure to publish it online on github/packagist, so that it can be remotely available from packagist repository to everyone, not just from your local path one.